# Parsing the output of FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I can see that there are 2 types of responses:

1. Windows
2. Unix

Examples

```
"08-25-12  06:52AM            139874418 3.03.06P13.12NB.rar"  
"-r-xr-xr-x   1 owner    group               1 Jun  3  1999 NotCurrentYear.txt"
```

I need to parse it and I used the following logic:

```
AnalyzedFolder folderToBeAnalyzed = new AnalyzedFolder();
                folderToBeAnalyzed.Name = folder;
                Job.AnalyzedFolders.Add(folderToBeAnalyzed);


                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBoxFTPSite.Text + folder);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBoxFTPUserName.Text, textBoxFTPPassword.Text);

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);


                string[] outputlines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                foreach (string info in outputlines)
                {
                    var tokens = info.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    string name;
                    string type;
                    string size;
                    DateTime dateModified;
                    string lsLine;

                    if (tokens.Length == 4) //WINDOWS
                    {
                        name = tokens[3];
                        if (tokens[2] == "<DIR>")
                        {
                            type = "D";
                            size = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            type = "F";
                            size = tokens[2];
                        }
                        dateModified = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1], "MM-dd-yy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        lsLine = info;
                        FTPFolderEntity entity = new FTPFolderEntity() { FolderName = folder, Name = name, Type = type, Size = size, DateModified = dateModified, LSLine = lsLine };
                        folderToBeAnalyzed.Entities.Add(entity);
                    }
                    else //UNIX
                    {
                    }
                }
```

The problem is that for this file:

```
"11-15-12  10:02PM                  324 Copy (10) of 1040.txt.zip"
```

because of the spaces, the logic fails. Also, like this bug, I suspect I may run into other problems also.  Can anyone guide me for a better parsing method please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *Regular Expression* here to remove extra *Whitesapces*:

```
string info = "11-15-12  10:02PM                  324 Copy (10) of 1040.txt.zip";
string result = Regex.Replace(info, @"\s\s+", " ");
```

After that you will get `result` as

```
// result = "11-15-12 10:02PM 324 Copy (10) of 1040.txt.zip";
```

**ADDED**, If you want to limit your tokens assuming the first is always the date, second is the time, and rest is your fileName or something:

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(info, @"\s+");

var newTokens = new string[] 
{ 
    tokens[0], 
    tokens[1], 
    tokens[2],
    tokens[3] + ' ' + tokens[4] + ' ' + tokens[5] + ' ' + tokens[6]
};
```

Comment: Its good but still it will give 7 tokens and my logic would fail. Any better idea than just counting tokens ?

Comment: How many tokens do you want? As it is not clear in the question so i thought you want to remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a split using a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx).

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(info, @"\s+");
```